# Applescript: Break a set of lines into blocks based on a condition

Tags: applescript, text-parsing, automator

I have an Automator service for uploading images and returning URLs to a text editor.
It works very well, but there's something I want to improve:

When the workflow starts, Automator will get all images in a folder and upload them to an FTP server.
Then it returns a result like below:

```
("http://url/0530/pic01/pic-01.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic01/pic-02.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic01/pic-03.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic01/pic-04.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic02/pic-01.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic02/pic-02.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic02/pic-03.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic02/pic-04.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic03/pic-01.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic03/pic-02.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic03/pic-03.jpg",
"http://url/0530/pic03/pic-04.jpg")
```

And the workflow gets these strings and puts them in a new text document.
Finally, here is the result in a text editor:

```
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-01.jpg 
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-04.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-01.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-04.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-01.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-04.jpg
```

But I want it to be:

```
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-01.jpg 
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-04.jpg

http://url/0530/pic02/pic-01.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-04.jpg

http://url/0530/pic03/pic-01.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-04.jpg
```

I think I can use AppleScript in Automator to do this before the result is sent to the text editor.
Do you have any coding advice?

===================================================

Thanks @ user309603 and @ mklement0 so much!!

I choose pure applescript method.
Here is my code in automator that run applescript in workflow:

```
on run {input, list}

    set txtG to first item of input

    repeat with txtLine in items 2 thru -1 of input
        if txtLine contains "-01" then set txtG to txtG & linefeed
        set txtG to txtG & linefeed & txtLine
    end repeat

    return txtG

end run
```

Comment: Please clarify if you need to process the raw FTP-server return value or the cleaned-up URL lines. Also, please clarify the criterion for breaking into blocks: is it enough to look for `-01.` in each line; or does the path up to the filename component need to be examined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure applescript solution.
I would prefer mklement0's awk-solution. It is much faster if you have long URL-lists.

```
set txt to "http://url/0530/pic01/pic-01.jpg 
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-01.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-01.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-04.jpg
http://url/0530/pic04/pic-01.jpg"

set txtG to first paragraph of txt

repeat with txtLine in paragraphs 2 thru -1 of txt
    if txtLine contains "-01" then set txtG to txtG & linefeed
    set txtG to txtG & linefeed & txtLine
end repeat

return txtG
```

Comment: +1 for a clean AppleScript-only solution. `awk` certainly makes for much shorter code (and is faster, as you point out), but using `do shell script` introduces issues with respect to line breaks; took me a while to get it right (see my revised answer).

Answer (score 1):

The following AppleScript snippet demonstrates the approach you can use in principle - I'm unclear on the exact circumstances:

If you **must process the *raw* result**:

```applescript
# Sample input text.
set txt to "(\"http://url/0530/pic01/pic-01.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic01/pic-02.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic01/pic-03.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic01/pic-04.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic02/pic-01.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic02/pic-02.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic02/pic-03.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic02/pic-04.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic03/pic-01.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic03/pic-02.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic03/pic-03.jpg\",
\"http://url/0530/pic03/pic-04.jpg\")"

# Group (break into blocks) by files containing "-01."
set txtGrouped to do shell script ¬
  "printf %s " & quoted form of txt & " | tr -d '()\"'" & ¬ 
        " | awk -F, 'NR>1 && /-01\\./ { print \"\" } { print $1 }'" ¬
  without altering line endings
```

If you **already have a *cleaned-up* set of URL-only lines**:

```applescript
# Sample input text.
set txt to "http://url/0530/pic01/pic-01.jpg 
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic01/pic-04.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-01.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic02/pic-04.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-01.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-02.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-03.jpg
http://url/0530/pic03/pic-04.jpg"

# Group (break into blocks) by files containing "-01."
set txtGrouped to do shell script ¬
  "printf %s " & quoted form of txt & ¬ 
        " | awk 'NR>1 && /-01\\./ { print \"\" } { print }'" ¬
  without altering line endings
```

Uses `do shell script` to have `awk` perform the desired grouping.

Note:

- `without altering line endings` is required to prevent AppleScript from replacing `\n` chars in the output with Mac-style `\r` line endings.
- The result will have a trailing `\n` char, even if the input didn't. To fix this, use:

  ```
  set txtGrouped to text 1 thru ((length of txtGrouped) - 1) of txtGrouped
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to always divide the list items into paragraphs grouped by four, here is an applescript you can put in an automator action:

```
set l to input as list
set r to ""
repeat with n from 1 to (count l) by 4
    set r to r & item n of l & return & item (n + 1) of l & return & item (n + 2) of l & return & item (n + 3) of l & return & return
end repeat
return r
```

Clarify if instead what you need is to group all the versions of one pic together, but it won't always be 4 each, and that the script needs to check the file names to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution : This script checks the name of the parent folder for each file, when the folder name is not the same, it add a blank line.

Append the `Run Shell Script` action into your workflow, select the "**/bin/bash**" shell and select "**to stdin**"

Put this script in the `Run Shell Script` action :

```
awk -F/ '{f=$(NF - 1); if (NR==1) {fName=f} else if (f != fName) {print ""; fName=f} print}' < "/dev/stdin"
```